# Best way of creating a database table sortable by a column

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have a table with unsorted rows and want to make them sortable by a column. I want the table to be sortable by a column, so I create a sort_by column.

The table now looks like this:

```
ID  Data   sort_by
--  -----  -------
27  Blahh  1  
54  Blahh  2  
57  Blahh  3  
1   Blahh  4
```

Now I want to insert a row in second position (sort_by = 2). Then I'll have to update sort_by for all rows > 2 with sort_by += 1. That's a lot of updates if I have a few million rows.

So, is there a canonical way of doing this? Of course I could have larger steps between columns and insert new rows in the gaps etc, but is there an *aesthetically pleasing* way, i.e. not a hack?

The sorting is done manually by users. A good phrase to google for = upvote, everything I try turns up ways to sort table in some DBMS or some framework. :)

Comment: Step 1 - identify the sort criteria.

Comment: It's sorted by hand, by my users. Think products you want to present on the start page of a web shop - what the marketing team thinks will sell. Updated the question.

Comment: When using SQL, sorting is always done by the use of an `ORDER BY` clause rather than by an implicit column. If an `ORDER BY` isn't used, the sequence can't be guaranteed. (Of course, an `ORDER BY` needs to reference columns in some way.) You might consider a secondary table where users can modify some _weighting_ criteria so that higher/lower _weights_ can influence sequencing. Modifying "millions" of rows each time isn't very reasonable. A Q&D method could be to increment `sort_by` by 100 or even 1000 rather than by 1.

Comment: This is the wrong kind of thinking. A user can sort 10 rows, not 100 rows, and certainly not a million rows. Perhaps a `featured` flag is handy with sorting options on the price/recency/color/whatever marketing thinks will seel is a better approach?

Comment: It's an hypothetical question. Imagine hyper-intelligent, ultra-fast, omni-scient alien invaders that sort the table. :)

Comment: Hypothetical questions are of topic :P [Look at my answer, even hypothetically speaking, manual ordering is an unoptimal solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24296994/764357). Focus on why you are ordering, not just a raw order.

Comment: In the actual case there are 188 rows. Those are sorted by hand. There could easily have been 288 rows. The products example is just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways I can think of.

1) Change sort_by to a decimal.  You will always[a] be able to insert a new row with more decimal places between existing values.

2) Turn your table into a linked list by replacing `sort_by` with `comes_after_ID`.  This is a foreign key pointing to `YourTable.ID`.

```
ID  Data   Comes_after_ID
--  -----  --------------
27  Blahh  NULL
54  Blahh  27
57  Blahh  54 
1   Blahh  57
```

With the second design it would be easier to do the ordering in application code rather than SQL.

Either way a drag-and-drop GUI can hide this implementation from the user.

[a] Always(TM) is limited to the resolution of decimals on your system, of course.  Eventually you will have to re-sequence your items.  But this can be done as a monthly job rather than as the user processes input.

Comment: Two good ways to solve the problem, thank you. Especially like the pragmatic yet quite elegant decimal.

Comment: The linked list might not be so useful when a subset of data is wanted, with records that are not sequential.

Answer (score 1):

**No one sorts a million rows by hand.** What you have here is a [classic XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

You are asking:

> How can I sort a million rows in an SQL database?

When you should be asking:

> How can I promote certain products in an online shop that is managed in a traditional Relational Database Management System?

The former requires a bunch of hacky solutions such as weightings, or decimal columns with ever widening precision, or in database linked lists. All of which are prone to error are counter-intuitive and ignore the problem domain.

You comment says:

> Think products you want to present on the start page of a web shop - what the marketing team thinks will sell

Well, what kinds of products do I want on the front page? Featured products, products that are on sale, products that are new, products that about to go out of stock...

```
-- Wacky featured items are random!
SELECT * FROM products WHERE featured = True ORDER BY RANDOM LIMIT 10;
-- More than 20% wow, thats a great deal!
SELECT * FROM products WHERE discount > 0.2 ORDER BY discount ASC LIMIT 10;
-- New stock, tell me about it!
SELECT * FROM products WHERE added_to_database < now()-24hours ORDER BY added_to_database LIMIT 10;
-- These items are about to disappear for ever, buy now!
SELECT * FROM products WHERE stock_number < 20 ORDER BY stock_number LIMIT 10;
```

Think about why you want to order them, not how to order them. This way you can get just some based on some criteria, and it more closely models the domain you are working in.